# Not able to deselect p:selectManyButton after select in primefaces 5.3

Tags: primefaces

In 5.3 i am not able to deselect p:selectManyButton using p:ajax event="change". But using keyboard tab key (and enter key) is working fine. 
sample code:

```
<p:selectManyButton value="#{testBean.selectedOptions}" >
<f:selectItem itemLabel="b" itemValue="b" /> 
<f:selectItem itemLabel="u" itemValue="u" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="i" itemValue="i" />
<p:ajax event="change" update="@this"/>
</p:selectManyButton>

<p:commandButton value="Submit" update="display"/>
<p:dataList id="display" value="#{testBean.selectedOptions}" var="font" emptyMessage="No fonts selected">
<h:outputText value="#{font}" style="font-weight: bold" />
</p:dataList>
```

Comment: Hi, Please do some searching next time. I posted your title in google and within 1 minute I found the answer...https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/790

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. In Primefaces 5.3 they have added keyboard functionality.They have written the code in primefaces.js file. I dont want the keyboard feature for SelectManyButton. So i just removed the focus, keydown and blur events for SelectManyButton from primefaces.js file. Now it is working fine. primefaces.js file can be extracted from primefaces.jar file.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in PrimeFaces 5.2.14 and up, 5.3.1 and up and 6.0-SNAPSHOT and up. See https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/790